# Segmentation fault from filling Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have been at this for 4.5 hours trying to figure out why this doesn't work. Still no luck. I keep getting a segmentation fault or the List never is displayed despite the build succeeding.

> > **SimpleVector.h**

```
// SimpleVector class template
#ifndef SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#define SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class SimpleVector
{
private:
    struct Link{
        int data;
        Link *next;
    };
   Link *head;
public:
   // Default constructor
   SimpleVector()
      {head = NULL;}

   // Destructor declaration
   ~SimpleVector();

   void linkList(int);

   //void insertLink(T);

   void displayList();
};

//Destructor for SimpleVector

SimpleVector::~SimpleVector(){
    Link *linkPtr;
    Link *nextPtr;

    nextPtr = head;

    while(linkPtr !=  NULL){
        nextPtr = linkPtr->next;
    }

    delete linkPtr;

    linkPtr = nextPtr;
}

//Creation of List

void SimpleVector::linkList(int size){    
    Link *newLink = new Link; //create first link
    head = newLink; //

    head->data = size--;         //Fill the front with data
    head->next = NULL;     //Point the front to no where

    do{
        Link *end = new Link;   //Create a new link
        end->data = size--;     //Fill with data
        end->next = NULL;       //Point to no where
        head->next = end;       //Previous link will point to the end
       // head = end;             //Move to the end
    }while(size > 0);          //Repeat until filled
}

//Creation of Link and insertion
/*
template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::insertLink(T){

}
*/

//Function to print the entire list

void SimpleVector::displayList(){
    Link *linkPtr;

    linkPtr = head;

    while(linkPtr != NULL){
        cout<<setprecision(3)<<linkPtr->data;
        linkPtr = linkPtr->next;
    }
}

#endif
```

> **main.cpp**

```
// This program demonstrates the SimpleVector template.
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleVector.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
int SIZE = 10; // Number of elements

// Create a SimpleVector of ints.
SimpleVector intTable;

intTable.linkList(SIZE);

intTable.displayList();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *despite the build succeeding* -- A successful build only means that there are no syntax errors in your program.  It has nothing to do with whether the logic is correct or if your program will produce the right results.

Comment: What line produces the segmentation fault?

Comment: Your destructor is wrong, as it uses uninitialized local variables.  Your compiler didn't warn you of this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no it didn't

Comment: @EggplantMachina -- You declared `linkPtr`, never set it to anything, and then use it in the `while` loop.  Thus you are using an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in `linkList()` function.
This line `head->next = end;`

Lets say first node contains 10 then end contains 9(new node)
now `head->next = end`

means  `10 -> 9`

now new node `end` becomes 8

again `head->next = end`
means `10 -> 8`
 Previous 9 is lost.
.
.
.

Lastly it will become `10 -> 1`

Try this instead.

```
void SimpleVector::linkList(int size){    
    Link *newLink = new Link; //create first link
    head = newLink; //

    head->data = size--;         //Fill the front with data
    head->next = NULL;     //Point the front to no where
    Link *temp = head;
    do{
        Link *end = new Link;   //Create a new link
        end->data = size--;     //Fill with data
        end->next = NULL;       //Point to no where
        temp->next=end;//Previous link will point to the end
        temp=end;  //Now this has become previous link     
       // head = end;             //Move to the end
    }while(size > 0);          //Repeat until filled
}
```

It uses `temp` variable to points to the previous node then creates link between previous and `end`(newly created node)  and then temp becomes end.

Edit:

```
Link *linkPtr=head;
    Link *nextPtr;// = linkPtr->next;
    do
    {
        nextPtr = linkPtr->next;
        cout<<linkPtr->data<<"\t";
        delete linkPtr;
        linkPtr = nextPtr;
    }while(linkPtr!=NULL);
```

Try this. It deletes whole list

Comment: I tried this something like this earlier but no luck still. I thought it might have been something to do with displayresult so i changed it to a 10 iteration for loop but still doesnt display anything

Comment: @user64322 I guess you didn't read my comment in the main thread on the issues with the destructor.

Comment: Do you want to delete whole list in Destructor?

Comment: @user64322 -- Do you not see the obvious error in the destructor?   What is `linkPtr` set to?

Comment: Yup i see but i dont know what he want to do in the destructor? He is using linkptr->next which is not initialized also while(linkptr).

Comment: @user64322 -- The issue is that you just copied the destructor without one comment on why it's wrong.  The program you posted as an answer crashes when run on Visual Studio due to the destructor being faulty.

Comment: linkPtr has default value NULL and i didnt knew did he wanted to delete whole list in destructor. also my bad added comment